# OnPause method for GridView ListActivity - Android

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

There is a bit of a pattern used when displaying a ListView or GridView. Given the XML file and my first method shown, what will my corresponding second method be? How it is now, I am getting an exception that a RelativeLayout cannot be cast to an ImageView at this line of the second method shown: `ImageView v = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(i);` I know my gridView is a bunch of relativeLayouts but not sure how to access their drawables.

Here is myLayout.XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

ImageAdapter.getView()

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              ViewHolder holder;
              ImageHelper ih = new ImageHelper();
              if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);

              holder = new ViewHolder();
              holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

              convertView.setTag(holder);
              } else {
              holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
              }

              holder.icon.setImageBitmap(ih.decodeSampledBitmapFromImagePath(mList.get(position), 150, 150));

              return convertView;
          }
```

ViewGridView.OnPause()

```
    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewViewOutfits);
            int count = gridView.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                ImageView v = (ImageView) gridView.getChildAt(i);
                if (v != null) {
                    if (v.getDrawable() != null) v.getDrawable().setCallback(null);
                }
            }
            super.onPause();
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)((ViewGroup)gridView.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(0);
```

Comment: Thanks I'm sure that is right as the exception went away, but now I get a null pointer exception on the same line. I ended up deleting onPause and OnDestroy due to the fact the code setting the callback to null was causing nullPointerexceptions

Comment: GridView contains views that displayed in the screen only. I think thaht You trying to access Views that does not exists http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)